# If = one class, but has two classes

Tags: javascript

I have a validation script that validates two different classes. I want to add an additional class for some select boxes that generate an array onmouseover. Problem is, the select boxes have two classes, one for the validation, one for the array, and my script doesn't recognize it unless it has the exact name. If using the == it doesn't work at all, but using the = it tries to validate all the elements on my page, even those without any classes.

I'm wondering how I can make this the most efficient without breaking the rest of my pages using this script.

This is an example of the HTML

```
<div class="select-styled">
    <select id="pm" name="pm" class="selValidate pmpop" onmouseover="pmpop();">
        <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="">- Remove -</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the validation script

```
for (i=0; i<thisform.elements.length; i++) {
        if (thisform.elements[i].className = "selValidate" || thisform.elements[i].className == "req" || thisform.elements[i].className == "valfocus") {
//do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: `thisform.elements[i].className == "selValidate"`

Comment: It skips over the selValidate with the ==

Comment: your question is `why "selValidate" not equals "selValidate pmpop"` exactly

Comment: Ok, you understand that a single equals sign `=` is ASSIGNMENT, not comparison, while the double equals sign `==` is comparison (regardless of type) and `===` is type-strict comparison, right? The meaning of `==` and `=` is completely different. By using `=`, you are changing the className to "selValidate." That's why it always fires - because the condition will always be true. You need to check if `"selValidate"` is a substring of `className`.

Comment: Yeah @outis nihil, I've only been doing this for a couple of months, started very slowly, so I'm still trying to grasp some of these concepts. But that makes a lot more sense so thanks for explaining that.

Comment: If you look at the answers below, there are several ways to see if "selValidate" is one of the classes on the element. Use those instead of the comparison operator (`==`). Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)?

```
if (thisform.elements[i].className.match('selValidate')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

You can't use the assignment operator in an `if` because it will do that...*assign*.  The `==` is a comparison operator.  But you seem to want to check if one css class is set for an element that has many..

So `match()` would work better as it searches for the occurrence of a string within a string, rather than comparing two string literals to see if they're equal.

Also, `match()` can accept regular expressions, which can be powerful. :)

EDIT:

Per Barney's comment, I recommend using a regular expression (as I mentioned earlier) to avoid false matches where you might have a similar class name (e.g. **selValidate** and **selValidateOff** or something like that).

```
if (thisform.elements[i].className.match(/\bselValidate\b/)) {
    // now, really do stuff
}
```

Both are good, really. I just depends on how narrow you want your search to be.

[Here is a nice cheat sheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript) for getting started with regular expressions in JavaScript.

Comment: Ahh ok. I'm thinking this is exactly what I'm looking for. I tested it and there don't seem to be any errors and it's working with my other functions. Thank you!

Comment: To avoid edge case false positives (classes that contain the substring `selValidate`), you might want to use regular expression's word-break flag, `\b`: `/\bselValidate\b/`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with multiple classes, the `className` property lists each class separated by a space. So markup like:

```
<select id="pm" name="pm" class="selValidate pmpop" onmouseover="pmpop();">
```

has a `className` equal to `"selValidate pmpop"`.

To use JavaScript to find an individual class using `className`, you either need to use the String `.match` method to test against a regex that will find the class in the string, or you need to break the string up into searchable tokens.

Example of `.match`:

```
for (i = 0; i < thisform.elements.length; i += 1) {
    if (thisform.elements[i].className.match(/\bselValidate\b|\breq\b|\bvalfocus\b/g) { // relies on .match returning null for no match
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Example of breaking the string into searchable tokens:

```
for (i = 0; i < thisform.elements.length; i += 1) {
    var allClasses = thisform.elements[i].className.split(' ');
    if (allClasses.indexOf('selValidate') > -1 || allClasses.indexOf('req') > -1 || allClasses.indexOf('valfocus') > -1) { // relies on ECMAScript 5 Array.indexOf support
        //do stuff
    }
}

// or

for (i = 0; i < thisform.elements.length; i += 1) {
    var allClasses = thisform.elements[i].className.split(' ');
    for (var j = 0; j < allClasses.length; j += 1) {
        if (allClasses[j] == 'selValidate' || allClasses[j] == 'req' || allClasses[j] == 'valfocus') { // should work with any browser that supports JavaScript
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use something like [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList), but I don't know [what browsers you need to target](http://caniuse.com/classlist).

Example of `.classList`:

```
for (i = 0; i < thisform.elements.length; i += 1) {
    if (thisform.elements[i].classList.contains('selValidate') || thisform.elements[i].classList.contains('req') || thisform.elements[i].classList.contains('valfocus')) { // relies on ECMAScript 5 Array.indexOf support
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Also, only use `=` when you want to assign a value to the lefthand operator (that's what it's for).
`==` is a type-coercive equality (or "equal-ish") test, and `===` is a strict (non-coercive) equality test.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM method for this is `classList`. If you only care about IE 10+, it's your best bet:

```
thisform.elements[ i ].classList.contains( 'selValidate' );
```

If you need to support older browsers, use RegExp and `className`:

```
thisform.elements[ i ].className.match( /\bselValidate\b/ );
```

**EDIT**: [after running a few tests on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/classlist-contains-versus-classname-match), it appears that `classList` is often much faster (the only browser that this isn't the case for is IE11). For this reason – and because `classList.contains` is an API designed to do precisely the task in question (whereas `className.match` is a kludge) – I'd recommend using the `classList` method if you can afford to ditch IE9 and below.

If you want to reap the speed benefits where possible but still support all browsers, here's a polyfill:

```
function hasClass( element, className ){
  if( element.classList && element.classList.contains ){
    hasClass = function classList_contains( element, className ){
      return element.classList.contains( className );
    }
  }
  else {
    hasClass = function className_match( element, className ){
      return new RegExp( '\\b' + className + '\\b' ).test( element.className );
    }
  }

  return hasClass( element, className );
}
```

Comment: What would be the difference if I used .match('selValidate') vs .classList.contains('selValidate'), considering only using IE10+ as this is for a company intranet?

Comment: [Based on the test I just set up, it appears to be slightly faster](http://jsperf.com/classlist-contains-versus-classname-match). But really the best thing about it is that it's functionality designed specifically to deal with your problem, whereas string and regular expression methods are hacks to infer what you're after. By using the `classList.contains` method, it's immediately clear what your code is doing.

Comment: @quesoflorecido after [running a few more tests](http://jsperf.com/classlist-contains-versus-classname-match), it appears that it's usually faster and sometimes (Firefox) orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, check for class existence instead of class-name comparison using

```
   $(thisform.elements[i]).hasClass('selValidate');
```

If you want Javascript only solution the use this library [classie](https://github.com/desandro/classie) which helps to check the existence of a class using hasClass() method.